# Build a database of folder directory

Tags: python, mysql, mongodb, sqlite, database

I want to know how to build a database from the folders stored in given directory. And any changes that are made to the database are directly stored in the respective folders as well. For example: Album art fetched for the music albums are stored in their respective folders and the database is updated to show that the album has cover art. I'm writing this program in python.